# Epic feat: self concealment cumulate with other "miss chance" abilities or spells?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, rogue, epic-tier, concealment

One of my players uses in combat the spell *displacement* (PH 223) allowing the 50% miss chance of attacks.

He also has the epic feat "self concealment" (10%). This feat is on the -epic level handbook pag 66- which is d&d 3.0. (as far as I am aware there is no manual for epic levels in d&d3.5).

We know that the effect of the feat does not stack with the effect of the spell (60% is not allowed).
But the player is asking me (the dungeon master) to roll first if I pass his *displacement* (50% miss) and then roll again if I pass his self concealment (10% miss).

The player also has the prestige class of perfect Wight (epic handbook page 34). When the player becomes incorporeal it allows for a miss chance of 50%.

Does this mean that to hit him I need to roll the dice to pass 3 miss chance (50% 50% and 10%)?

Is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### None of them stack, and rolling multiple ***is*** stacking them; use the highest miss-chance.

*Player's Handbook*, [152](https://dndsrd.net/combatModifiers.html#concealment-miss-chance):

> Multiple concealment conditions (such as a defender in a fog [[DMG 94]](https://dndsrd.net/wildernessAndEnvironment.html#fog) and under the effect of a *blur* [[PH 206]](http://dndsrd.net/spellsAtoB.html#blur) spell) do not stack.

If the concealment and the incorporeality miss chances were both rolled, the chance of a successful hit would be 25% (50% × 50%). If the Self Concealment were rolled after that, that would reduce the chance of a hit by a further 10% of the 25%, so 22.5% chance of a successful hit.

So, the fact that the chances do not stack also *implicitly* means that the miss chance is rolled only once, otherwise the percentages would *effectively* stack, which they explicitly **do not**.

The general rule is that unless specified otherwise, only unnamed numerical bonuses and instantaneous effects stack or otherwise combine to greater effect [[PH 171]](https://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#combining-magical-effects). So, the best miss chance any creature is likely to find is 50% for total concealment, and you don't roll more than once unless an ability *explicitly* tells you to, such as the blind-fight feat [[PH 89]](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#blind-fight)

> ...every time you miss because of concealment, you can reroll your miss chance percentile roll one time to see if you actually hit.

---

For what it's worth, the *Rules Compendium*, which is not regarded as a primary source by some, *also* states that multiple miss chances don't stack [32]:

> If a creature receives miss chances from multiple sources, such as from being incorporeal and having concealment, only the highest miss chance applies.

Comment: True enough. Fixing now.